# Filtering a binding: Property <query> not found in type <Entity>

Tags: sapui5

The error is right, there is no property named  because that's the search query. I don't see what's going on, I've implemented filters for search queries before. This error occurs before any call is made to the OData service.

```
onSearchQualification: function(evt){

    // create model filter
    var filters = [];
    var query = evt.getParameter("query");
    if (query && query.length > 0) {
        var filter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Title", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, query);
        filters.push(filter);
    }

    // update list binding
    var list = evt.oSource.getParent().getParent(); //this.getView().byId("QualificationSelectionList");
    var binding = list.getBinding("items");
    binding.filter(filters);

    //this._oList.getBinding("items").filter(aFilters, "Application");
},
```

[image: What now?]

Comment: I don't think problem is due to search. It might be a problem with UI binding. Can you paste your view ?

Answer (score 0):

The `<items>` aggregation for the `<List>` element was missing.

Comment: You can accept your own answer to inform others that this issue is resolved now